# How to get Date from DateTimePicker.CustomFormat

Tags: c#

How i can get only Date with datetime datatype from DateTimePicker.CustomFormat("dd");

```
datetimepicker1.CustomFormat = "dd";
```

it gives me full date but i need onlye Day on month like 05
I am also Storing the datetimepicker value in the database and the database column have datetime datatype

Comment: you need to set Format of the DateTimePicker control to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you have set only the `CustomFormat` Property of the `DateTimePicker` control without Changing the `Format` of the `DateTimePicker` control to `Custom`.

**Solution :** You need to set `Format` of the `DateTimePicker` control to `Custom`

Try This:

```
datetimepicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
datetimepicker1.CustomFormat = "dd";
```

**Solution 2:** if you want to get only `Date` part from the Selected Date value you can use `Day` property of DateTimePicker.

Try This:

```
int day=dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
```

Comment: i am storing DateTimePicker value in database and the database column have datetime datatype i want the Day in datetime datatype

Comment: @DaniDanish: if you want to get only Date value from datetimepicker use `Day` property, check my edited answer with `Solution 2`.

Comment: i want to store it in database and database column have datetime datatype

Comment: @DaniDanish: if you want to store only date part in database then change column datatype from `DateTime` to `int`, so that you can store the integer date value.

Comment: i dont want to change the column datatype there were allready records stored in it ...

Comment: i dont want to change the column datatype there were allready records stored in it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd");
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code,

```
datetimepicker1.SelectedDate.Day();
```